# Distinguish different type of Comments

Tags: java, design, comments

I would like to provide design decisions in the comments as well. I want design decision comments to be distinguishable from function contract comments, on cursory examination of source code.

How to go about it?

Comment: Keep that stuff in the design document, not the source code.  You can certainly add a comment in the source along the lines of `See Section 3.4 of the SDD for why we're doing this stupid thing` but don't copy and paste section 3.4 of the SDD into the code itself.  That's just creating more work for yourself.

Comment: To ride on John's coattails, put your design documentation on your wiki. In your comments, put a link to your documentation.

Comment: @JohnBode

"but don't copy and paste section 3.4 of the SDD into the code itself. That's just creating more work for yourself."


I thought, not maintaining separate design doc would be less work, and the code and design decision would be more in sync if present in code itself. But I am new to programming, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @JohnBode I disagree that *all* this stuff should be in the design document.  The design document should describe high level decisions that affect understanding of the system as a whole.  Decisions that are local to a single module should be documented within that module as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function contract comments should be in javadoc comments rather than plain comments (i.e. comments beginning with `/**`).  Many syntax-highlighting editors are able to highlight these with a different colour to other comments (e.g. eclipse).

File history/copyright/licence comments should be confined to the top of the file.

Work-in-progress/task-related comments should be tagged with an appropriate keyword (e.g. `TODO` or `FIXME`) which again many syntax-highlighting editors can highlight (again eclipse is able to do this).

All other comments should exist to document design decisions, so can be distinguished easily due to be being standard comments that aren't at the top of the file.

Answer (score 7):

You could try creating [Custom JavaDoc Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677564/how-to-create-custom-javadoc-tags).  Your design decisions could have an `@why` tag or something.  I've always thought comments that answer the question "Why?" tend to be the most useful.

That said, I agree with @JohnBode and @BobDalgleish that you don't want to paste pages of your design docs into your code, but an abbridged "TL;DR" summary of those docs could be really helpful sometimes.

Comment: “Why comments” are the only ones that can not be replaced with code: Given a programming language that is expressive enough, all other comments can be replaced with code, and the result will be more readable, and maintainable.

Comment: @richard +1 insightful enough to tweet: https://twitter.com/GlenKPeterson/status/747545611185029124